# How to replace this string using regular expression in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace X with Y in vim with the regular expression `^+.*X$`, which begin with `+` and end with `X`.

Comment: Haven't tried it with regex, but you can check http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like this,

```
  %s/\(^+.*\)X$/\1Y/g
```

Answer (score 5):

Another variant, using `\zs` to indicate start of match

```
%s/^+.*\zsX$/Y/
```

See `:h \zs` for more info

Answer (score 5):

Yet another alternative, use the [`:g`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g) command to operate in lines beginning with `+` and replace the final `X`:

```
g/^+/s/X$/Y
```